# React.JS: Print Map of object in render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a object like:

```
Family:
  Parent0:
     BirthPlace: "dsa"
     Birthday: "2021-01-04"
     Relationship: "dsa"
     SurnameAndName: "dasdsa"
 Parent1:
     BirthPlace: "dsa"
     Birthday: "2021-01-04"
     Relationship: "dsa"
     SurnameAndName: "dasdsa"
```

Now I should print for every Parent the information.

I have tried to render the information like this:

```
          {Object.keys(_Family).map(function(key, index){
            Object.keys(_Family[key]).map(function(key1, index1){
              <p>{_Family[key][key1].SurnameAndName}</p>
            })
          })}
```

where _Family is my doc.Family

How can I print for every Parent the information??

EDIT:

```
       {Object.keys(_Family).map(function(key, index){
        return Object.keys(_Family[key]).map(function(key1, index1){
          return <p>{_Family[key][key1].SurnameAndName}</p>
        })
      })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to `return` the paragraph from the `map`.
Add `return` and let me know if it works.

Add a `key` prop to each paragraph to remove the warning.
Also try this approach instead:

```js
{Object.values(_Family)
.map((member, index) => (<p key={index}>Full name: {member.SurnameAndName}</p>))}
```

MDN `Object.values()`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values

Comment: mmmh where?? there? `return <p>{_Family[key][key1].SurnameAndName}</p>` ?

Comment: yes, in both `map`s, you have to return what you want to see in the UI. I would make a separate function for this.

Comment: I don't understand, in both? Like I edit in the post?

Comment: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.
this is the error message

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231240/discussion-between-gabriel-lupu-and-jack23).